# Error 500 in Magento

Tags: magento

I have successfully installed Magento in mylocalhost server and when i tried to open the admin and index i got this error

```
[Wed Aug 01 00:47:57.088443 2018] [php7:error] [pid 12976] [client ::1:48615] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')\n#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/m...')\n#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n#4 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)\n#5 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Cache/Frontend/Ada in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209, referer: http://localhost/
```

Have tried to do chmod 777 /var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache still returning error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write permissions needed on your cache directory

chmod 777 /var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache

Or even just the full var directory:

chmod 777 /var/www/html/magento2/var - R

**For security, those permissions aren't recommended on a production setting but should be fine for local development.**

You basically need to make that directory writable by the web server, but that depends on your system setup and is a more complex answer. Probably overkill for this context

Comment: 777 not secure, it require proper owner of folder and 755 permission

Comment: As I stated. Without knowing the user the web server is running as this is the simplest solution. As this is a development machine there should not be an issue with this approach

Comment: 777 Is not the safest solution, I suggest first try to create an user which belongs to the web server group (apache/nginx) and then make that user owner of the magento2 folder

Comment: still returning same error [Thu Aug 02 10:40:11.092146 2018] [php7:error] [pid 3371] [client ::1:50549] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/magento2/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack trace:\n#0

Comment: That's not the same error, look at the path. Try changing permissions on the cache directory too

Answer (score 0):

just change the permissions of directory "/var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache" to 777
using following command.

```
 sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache
```

If there is no such directory, probably you need to create directory at given location and change the permissions.

Comment: 777 not secure, it require proper owner of folder and 755 permission

Comment: still returning same error [Thu Aug 02 10:40:11.092146 2018] [php7:error] [pid 3371] [client ::1:50549] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/magento2/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack trace:\n#0